# Magento V1 to V2 migrate changes

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I will migrate magento from 1 to 2, and then I will like to migragte the changes manually. I know that I can do it with The incremental migration tool, but the problem is I dont have sudo permission in the share server, because that there wont be any m2_cl_* tables to track the changes. How should I do it? can I run the migration tool every time I want to migrate the changes? or it will messed up, like it will create duplicated orders, products and so on?

Comment: what changes exactly? migration tool will sync everything from m1>m2

Comment: What happen if I run migration tool multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

after full migration you need to use delta migration:

1. Data that customers added via storefront (created orders, reviews,
   changes in customer profiles, etc.)
2. All operations with orders, products, and categories in the Magento
   Admin panel

`bin/magento migrate:delta`

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-migrate.html

Comment: That is the incremental migration tool , right? I am not able to do it , because my I cannot create any  m2_cl_* tables in magento 1 database.

Comment: tables will be created once you run it

Comment: I cant do it. I use a share server. It doesn't allow the migration tool to create these tables.

Comment: then move your shop to another server, create account, sync files, change DNS, and do your work - that simple